# Does Windows 10 track which storage devices are connected to it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, fat32

Does Windows 10 keep a log or history of USB storage devices that are connected to it?  For example, if I connect a USB drive to my Windows 10 computer and access some files on a USB drive with it, is there any record stored on the computer that it accessed that drive and if so, is there any record as to what it did with the files?  I think the answer to both questions are no, assuming that the computer did not have extra software (not part of a standard Windows installation) installed to track that.  Is that correct?

If the USB drive is Fat32 formatted, does the drive itself keep track of what device accessed the files?  I think the answer to that is also no.  That the file system will only track the date/timestamp when files were modified, created, or accessed, but not specifically which devices accessed them.  Is that correct?

Comment: Single question per post please. Also, what is your concern, what are you worried about? Are you trying to hide something?

Comment: Windows keeps track of USB devices in general based on their device identification.  It's trivial for an Administrator to determine if a USB mass storage device has been connected to your system.